# Search particular text file for a value on remote computer by using WMIC

Tags: powershell, cmd, wmi, wmic

```
wmic /node:remoteip datafile where "name='C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\preferences'"
```

By using code above i can get "preferences" file specs such as size, type, lastaccessed etc.

I need to search specific value in this preferences file. How to do this?

Comment: Wmic is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic), so you'd better try something else. For exaple, read the file via UNC path in Powershell.

Comment: As you tagged `PowerShell`, you should use PowerShell [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview)s along with the [Get-CimInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) which returns an **object** with properties rather than a text file.

Comment: in my network remote cmdlets doesnt work. I tried get-ciminstance amd got error;  HRESULT 0x80338126,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand.

Comment: That is probably because [WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/winrmsecurity) is disabled.

Comment: `... get FileSize,LastAccessed` or `... get fileSize,LastAccessed /value`

Comment: you were right. The winrm service disabled.